# Is there a way to find out which Bluetooth device is plugged into which USB port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, ubuntu-16.04, bluez

I'm using two Bluetooth adaptors with BlueZ, both are the same device but with different types of antenna, is there any method to find out which usb port the identifier on BlueZ (hci0/hci1) is referring to?

I can discover the MAC address of the device through hcitool dev, so if there was a way to discover which USB port the adaptor with that MAC address was connected to, that would also solve my problem.

As both the adaptors are the same model, lsusb does not provide any identifying information I can use.

Using Ubuntu 16.04. I am looking for a solution in any form, whether it is a shell command or java/C/python/etc.

Comment: Here's an ugly workaround: connect your phone or some device to one of the Bluetooth adaptors and then copy a picture/file to the computer and use online tools to trace where the file/picture came from.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to find a way to do this automatically, as it will need to be redone every time the adaptors are disconnected. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer should point you in the right direction, though doesn't give you a complete solution.

You should be able to use the contents of the "sys" filesystem, under `/sys/class/bluetooth`:

```
$ ls -lA /sys/class/bluetooth/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Dec  8 09:35 hci0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Dec  8 09:35 hci1 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f201000.serial/tty/ttyAMA0/hci1
```

That's from my Raspberry Pi, with a builtin adapter on the /dev/ttyAMA0 UART interface, and an added Bluetooth adapter on USB.  The information in the symlink target technically tells you which physical port the adapter is plugged into.

If you're not familiar with the convention for USB device numbering (which forms a tree of nodes, since a port can have a USB hub with multiple additional ports, etc), look under /sys/bus/usb/devices, and match that up with the "lsusb" output and you should figure it out.  In my case, "lsusb" shows that adapter as "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0", which if I recall corresponds to the "1-3" stuff in the /sys/class/bluetooth path (where unfortunately it appears the bus value uses index origin 1, while the device number uses index origin 0 so the 4 turns into a 3 there).

If you experiment with moving your USB adapter around to different physical ports, you should be able to work out the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you need, but you should find detailed information about the devices attached through the following command:-

```
hciconfig -a
```

This will give you enough details to identify the specific devices. You can add this in a shell script and use some string manipulation and conditionals to figure out your devices.

In my case, I have one BT dongle connected, and running `hciconfig -a` give the following output:-

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:16:A4:06:AC:E6  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:670 acl:0 sco:0 events:46 errors:0
    TX bytes:2495 acl:0 sco:0 commands:46 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'youssif'
    Class: 0x0c0000
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x22bb
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x22bb
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

If this is not sufficient, you can use also use a combination of `lsusb` and `hciconfig` commands to figure out which device is connected to what port.